# Xcode 6 variable inspector showing nil

Tags: objective-c, xcode, scope

I've got something like this:

```
NSArray* titleColors = @[defaultColorForTitles, defaultColorForTitles, defaultColorForTitles]];
```

If I `NSLog` it out, I get:

```
2015-02-09 15:26:21.984 project[27352:1574376] (
    6c6c6c,
    red,
    blue
)
```

Yay!

But if I set a breakpoint at the next line and hover over the variable, instead of seeing the array values (like I'd expect), it shows `nil`. Is this expected? Is my Xcode broken? What's going on?

[image]

Comment: I have seen this before too. Something odd where I had to hover over it a couple of times before it wanted to show me what was really going on. What type of object are you passing into the array? Just NSStrings?

Comment: Yep. Strings. So strange!

Comment: Just for curiosity sake if you hover over it a few times does it show correctly?

Comment: Nope, nil every time.

Comment: The last thing I wonder is if you replace what is in the array with some @"textStuff" does it still show nil?

Comment: Yeah, seems to still show nil every time. Gah!

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/70605/discussion-between-skyler-lauren-and-remus).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you running a debug build? When hit your break point, does NSLog print out the value? If it does print out, but your inspector shows nil. It can be you are running a released build and compiler made an optimization there (mostly because that line is the last use of `titleColors`). That's my guess based on current information.

Comment: Yes, NSLog prints it out properly. I thought about that, hence why I'm asking if this is expected behavior (ARC-related?)

Comment: Turns out someone had switched the build to release without me knowing; switching it back to debug fixed the problem. Thanks!